# Need a great explanation of using MOQ syntax

Tags: c#, linq, moq

I seem to have problems getting MOQ syntax by example. I would like to have suggestions where to look, besides MOQ website, to comprehend usage of mocking various interfaces.

For example, I would like to understand how exactly I proceed mocking this or that interface method and be able, for example, to undestand why a developer writes things like this:

```
        daoMock.Setup(d => d.Get(It.Is<Expression<Func<ConfigurationEntity, bool>>>(e => ExpressionMatchesEntityWithKey(e, TestKey))))
               .Returns(new List<ConfigurationEntity> {configEntity});
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest checking the documentation. Here is a good list of examples: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: @Jakub too short comments. "// matching Func<int>, lazy evaluated' - for god's sake, where 'lazy evaluation' is in the line?

Comment: @AskarIbragimov Presumably they mean that the `Func<int>` isn't called straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github page, as suggested by @Jakub, is actually a great place to start.

Either way, I'll explain the example you posted.
Say you have this interface and this setup:

```
public interface IDao
{
    IEnumerable<ConfigurationEntity> Get(Expression<Func<ConfigurationEntity, bool>> expression) {...}
}

var daoMock = new Mock<IDao>();

daoMock.Setup(d => d.Get(It.Is<Expression<Func<ConfigurationEntity, bool>>>(e => ExpressionMatchesEntityWithKey(e, TestKey))))
               .Returns(new List<ConfigurationEntity> {configEntity});
```

This setup tells the mock to return a list containing `configEntity` **when**:

- the `Get` method is called
- with an argument of type `Expression<Func<ConfigurationEntity, bool>>`
- and `ExpressionMatchesEntityWithKey(e, TestKey)` (where `e` is the expression passed in as an argument) returns true.

So, basically, when you call the `Get` method on the mocked object, Moq will check if the argument is of the correct type, check if `ExpressionMatchesEntityWithKey(e, TestKey)` returns true, and then return a list with `configEntity`.

By default, if any of these requirements are not met, the mocked object will return the default value for `IEnumerable<ConfigurationEntity>`, which is `null`.

Now, you can retrieve the mocked object and do whatever you want with it.

```
IDao dao = daoMock.Object;
```